# Adding member to MUC in XMPP(SMACK)

Tags: java, xmpp, openfire, smack, multiuserchat

I am trying to create multi user chat using XMPP(smack). After creation of room when i try to join to chat room then there is no entry of joined member in **ofmucmember**.

Creation of room code is as below :

```
public void createMultiUserChatRoom(String roomName, String nickName) {

        MultiUserChatManager multiUserChatManager = MultiUserChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection);

        MultiUserChat multiUserChat = multiUserChatManager.getMultiUserChat(roomName+"@conference.localhost");

        try {
            multiUserChat.create(nickName);

            Form form = multiUserChat.getConfigurationForm();
            Form submitForm = form.createAnswerForm();

            List<FormField> formFieldList = submitForm.getFields();
            for (FormField formField : formFieldList) {
                if(!FormField.Type.hidden.equals(formField.getType()) && formField.getVariable() != null) {
                    submitForm.setDefaultAnswer(formField.getVariable());
                }
            }

            submitForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_persistentroom", true);
            submitForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_publicroom", true);
            submitForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_enablelogging", true);
            submitForm.setAnswer("x-muc#roomconfig_reservednick", false);
            submitForm.setAnswer("x-muc#roomconfig_canchangenick", false);
            submitForm.setAnswer("x-muc#roomconfig_registration", false);
            submitForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_passwordprotectedroom", false);
            submitForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_roomname", roomName);
             submitForm.setAnswer("muc#roomconfig_whois", Arrays.asList("none"));
            multiUserChat.sendConfigurationForm(submitForm);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Code for joining the created room is as below:

```
    public void joinMultiUserChatRoom(String userName, String roomName) {
            MultiUserChatManager manager = MultiUserChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection);

            MultiUserChat multiUserChat = manager.getMultiUserChat(roomName + "@conference.localhost");
            DiscussionHistory history = new DiscussionHistory();
            history.setMaxStanzas(0);
            try {
                multiUserChat.join(userName);
                multiUserChat.sendMessage(userName +" : You have joined the group : " + roomName);

                Presence presence = multiUserChat.getOccupantPresence(roomName + "@conference.localhost/" + userName);
                presence.setMode(Presence.Mode.available);
                connection.sendStanza(presence);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Response from server :

```
<message to="admin@localhost/Smack" id="h7axM-14" type="groupchat" from="team6@conference.localhost/roy"><body>roy : You have joined the group : team6</body><x xmlns="jabber:x:delay" stamp="20160623T12:15:50" from="team6@conference.localhost/roy"/></message>
presence :<presence to='admin@localhost/Smack' id='WR9Dy-12'><x xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user'><item affiliation='owner' jid='admin@localhost/Smack' role='moderator'></item></x><c xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/caps' hash='sha-1' node='http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack' ver='NfJ3flI83zSdUDzCEICtbypursw='/></presence>
```

I am not getting any error. Can anybody tell me where i am wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

When you fill the configuration form, you need to fill following sections:

```
<field
      label='Room Admins'
      type='jid-multi'
      var='muc#roomconfig_roomadmins'>
    <value>wiccarocks@shakespeare.lit</value>
    <value>hecate@shakespeare.lit</value>
  </field>

<field
          label='Room Owners'
          type='jid-multi'
          var='muc#roomconfig_roomowners'/>
```

Admins and Owner are saved in **ofMucAffiliation** table and if the configuration is updated and existing admin or owner is not mentioned then server assumes that it's affiliation has been changed to member, so it moves the entry to **ofMucMember** table.

Answer (score 0):

You don't get a member just because you join a room. After you have joined a room, you are a *Participant* in the terminology of XEP-0045.

Comment: Then how will that participant have entry in database?

Comment: I don't think that Openfire saves Participants in the Database

Comment: Yes, it saves members in database. I have checked it via adding it from openfire server.